# How Do I Make The Modal Open?

Tags: javascript

I am currently attempting to open a modal for these images. When I click them, nothing happens. My best guess is that it has something to do with the openModal function on the first two lines of the JS file, I think I need to change where it gets the document, but I am not too sure.

```js
function openModal(){
    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}
function closeModal(){
    document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function currentSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for ( i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active ", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<!--Gallery-->
  <section id="gallery">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <!--photo container-->
            <div class="photo-container">
                <div class="photo">
                    <img src="images/thumbnail_1.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" alt="">
                    <div class="photo-overlay">
                        <h3>Click to Enlarge</h3>
                        <p>We have several books fr you</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           
           <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content"></div>

        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numberText">1 / 9</div>
            <img src="images/thumbnail_1.jpg" style="width: 100%;" alt="image 1">
        </div>
         <!--Thumbnail Image Controls-->
        <div class="column">
            <img class="demo" src="images/thumbnail_1.jpg" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="image">
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that your openModal function is running on click? Can you inspect the div afterward to see if it gets set to display block?

Comment: Do you mean by looking at dev tools? When I click it doesn't show anything. The div itself is set to block, but the modal section is set to none so when I click, it will display block, its a bit tricky what is going on here. I could just post the github link, but I don't want to take too muc htime from others.